# Multiple (top) custom axes

Tags: axis, teechart

I'm discovering TeeChart for .Net winform; very good product.

I want to compare two or more sets of values for different periods. For example the temperatures of February and those of April. Thus I use my left axis for the temperature and want a x-axis for each month, z-stacking the charts. It actually works pretty "straightforwardly" except that the custom horizontal axis (for the dates) are drawn over each others. I would obviously like them to stack vertically.

I saw in some screenshots related to other problems on forums that it is possible. I am wondering if there is an already implemented parameter for this or do I need to override an axis event and do it myself?

PS: here is an illustration of what I currently have:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% about what you need to achieve here but probably you need to customize the position for each axis. You'll find some basic information about this in Tutorial 4. The *All features\Welcome !\Axes* section in the features demo may also be of help. Tutorials and features demo are available at TeeChart's program group. For a more complex and advanced example you can look at [this forums thread](http://www.teechart.net/support/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=10165&p=42266&#p42266).

If this doesn't help don't hesitate to let me know.

Comment: I didn't, before posting, find any example with the effect I am looking for. I will read the snippet you linked to see.
PS: I added a picture of my current result. It clarifies my problem.

Comment: @Max.gd where did you post the picture?

Comment: Didn't see the error message from Stackoverflow stipulating I am a too young member to post an image here. http://i44.tinypic.com/r1yfwi.png

Comment: @Max.gd thanks for the image. Yes, that's what I thought your problem is.

Comment: Thanks, then the thread you linked should do the trick?
It uses Chart1.MarginLeft at some point, does it correspond to the C# Chart1.Panel.MarginLeft?

Comment: @Max.gd yes, that thread should do. The code there is designed for left side horizontal axes, you should convert it to horizontal top axes. Exactly, your right with the margins thing.

Comment: Sorry but I don't figure out anyway to make it. This example, as you noted, is working horizontally. So it uses PositionPercent (Which I assume to be StartPosition(), after having set PositionUnits to Percent ni C#), which only works for horizontal axes. What do I miss?

Comment: @Max.gd it actually works for vertical axes, hence sets their position in horizontal coordinates. PositionPercent is not StartPosition in .NET, as told in Tutorial 4, it's RelativePosition.

Comment: Aaah! My thing still needs some fine tuning but it seems like you gave me all I needed. Thank you for your time.